# Не выходит оптимизировать sql запросы django

Tags: python, sql, django

Получаю по SQL запросу на каждый элемент images.
Если убрать {% if img.categories == category %} в шаблоне, то запросов нормальное количество, но как тогда их фиьтровать не совсем понятно.
Пробовал использовать {% regroup  by  as  %} в шаблоне, но тогда такое же большое количество запросов... Помогите оптимизировать это безобразие...
Спасибо.

В models.py

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Images(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img = ResizedImageField(upload_to='catalog')
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
```

Во views.py

```
def catalogManufacturer(request, url):
    args = {}
    args['catalog'] = Catalog.objects.get(url=url)
    args['categories'] = Categories.objects.filter(catalog=args['catalog'].id)
    args['images'] = Images.objects.filter(categories=args['categories'])
    return render_to_response('catalog-manufacturer.html', args)
```

Ну и шаблон.

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for img in images %}
            {% if img.categories == category %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{% cropped_thumbnail img "cropping" scale=1 %}">
                        <img src="{% cropped_thumbnail img "cropping" scale=0.6 %}" alt="{{img.name}}">
                    </a>
                    {{img.name}}
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: А напишите, откуда у вас берётся `cropped_thumbnail` (не факт что влияет, но на всякий случай)

Comment: И на заметку: модели лучше назвать `Category` и `Image`

Comment: Почему бы не запрашивать все изображения для категории через связь моделей? Category.image_set.all или category.images.all (не помню точно). Если категорий немного, то должно уменьшить количество запросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объекты типа QuerySet не обращаются к БД во время создания - эти объекты "ленивые" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). Это значит, что обращения к БД будут созданы тогда, когда это действительно необходимо. Например, во время итерации по элементам из QuerySet. Можно обернуть QuerySet в список, тогда все объекты будут получены из БД сразу же (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

```
args['images'] = list(Images.objects.filter(categories=args['categories']))
```

У такого подхода есть и недостаток - если объектов в БД столько, что они все сразу не влезут в память - вылетит исключение MemoryError. В таком случае можно написать простой генератор изображений, который будет таскать объекты не по-одному, а, например, по 100 за один запрос:

```
def queryset_gen(query):
    total_items = query.count()
    batch_size = 100
    fetched_items = 0
    batch_seeker = 0
    batch = list(query.all()[:batch_size])
    current_offset = batch_size
    while fetched_items < total_items:
        next_item = batch[batch_seeker]
        yield next_item
        batch_seeker += 1
        if batch_seeker == batch_size or batch_seeker == len(batch):
            batch_seeker = 0
            fetched_items += batch_size
            # [OFFSET:LIMIT]
            batch = list(query.all()[current_offset:batch_size])
            current_offset += batch_size
```

Comment: К сожалению оборачивание в список результатов не дало...     args['images'] = list(Images.objects.filter(categories=args['categories'])) Может я чего-то еще не понимаю? Буду рад разъяснениям...

Comment: Даже обернутый QuerySet по-прежнему генерирует много одиночных запрсов вместо одного? Попробуйте `list(Images.objects.filter(categories=args['categories']).all())` - был добавлен метод all(), но, судя по документации помочь не должно

Comment: Да и так и так много запросов.... Я думаю, что это как-то связанно с тем что в шаблоне несколько раз объект images проходит через циклы, но не уверен.

Comment: Если известно, что запросов много, может известно что это конкретно за запросы? У вас в модели есть внешний ключ и не факт, что для изображений автоматически джойнится связанная таблица. В SQLAlchemy, например, внешние ключи по умолчанию тоже ленивые. Чтобы все связанные таблицы автоматически загрузились, попробуйте https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related метод. Но в таком случае стоит очень внимательно следить за памятью.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не дал раньше. Запросы такого типа и они дублируются..... SELECT "catalog-categories"."id", "catalog-categories"."name", "catalog-categories"."catalog_id" FROM "catalog-categories" WHERE "catalog-categories"."id" = 18 Добавлю, что "catalog-categories" это модель категорий Categories.

Comment: Попробуйте select_related()  - этот метод явно делает JOIN для выбранного внешнего ключа. И вызов `{% if img.categories == category %}` не будет генерировать лишних запросов.

Comment: Да. Благодарю. Переписал на args['images'] = Images.objects.select_related('categories').filter(categories=args['categories']) И теперь запрос всего один. За раз выбирается по 100-120 полей, так что надеюсь проблем с памятью не возникнет.

Answer (score 0):

Странный у вас местами код конечно. Вот эта конструкция `Catalog.objects.get(url=url)` не падает?

Давайте немного перепишем ваши модели и попробуем понять что у вас в коде творится

Объявляем категорию (у вас это называется Catalog), тут вроде всё нормально

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Объявим модель изображения. У неё будет ссылка на категорию, в которой она представлена, имя и непосредственно изображение

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='catalog')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Что за вторая модель у вас Images я не понял, но вероятнее всего это ваши попытки использовать какой-то сторонний компонент (вероятнее всего django-resized - вообще указывать надо в тексте вопроса) - судя по коду он дополнительных запросов не генерирует. Теперь напишем view

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def CategoryManufacturer(request, id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=id)
    image_list = Image.objects.filter(category=category).select_related('category')
    args = {
        'category': category,
        'images': image_list
    }
    return render_to_response('catalog-manufacturer.html', args)
```

Что тут происходит?

Мы берём id из ссылки (у вас должен быть url вида `url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', ...)` и получаем категорию. Если категория не найдена, то get_object_or_404 вернёт 404 ошибку. Если категория есть, то мы получаем все изображения, которые есть в этой категории. Тут ещё стоит упомянуть о select_related, который подгружает к каждому изображению категорию без дополнительного запроса. Ну и отдаём в ответ

Что за cropped_thumbnail у вас в шаблоне я не знаю, но подозреваю, что вы просто намешали кучу компонентов и не знаете какой выбрать. Почистите код и всё встанет на свои места